# how can i resolve this problem publish_post hook not working

Tags: wordpress

```
public function when_post_published($ID, $post)
{

    global $post;
    echo $ID;
    echo var_dump($post);
    echo $_POST['post'];
    echo $_GET['post'].;

}
$this->loader->add_action('publish_post', $plugin_admin, 'when_post_published');
```

Comment: please be more specific. Describe, how exactly this one does not work and what did you try already to fix it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Please [edit] the question to explain "not working" by adding details like error messages and observed and desired behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a post is published/saved, it does not do it in a single script execution. It redirects to a different script, does the save, then redirects back to where you started. If you want to confirm that your hook is working, use update_option(), and delete the option immediately after displaying it so it's not latent (alternatively: you can make the option count up or something, there's quite a bit you could do, be creative).

Comment: i dont want to use update-option i just want the date when the post published.

Comment: when you publish the post then you want to get new date.